# Upgrading from springfox swagger2 to OpenApi 3 since spring boot 2.6.9 does not support swagger2. Seems like a conflict in jackson versions. Any idea?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson, swagger

Upgrading from springfox swagger2 to OpenApi 3 as we are updating the spring boot version to 2.6.9 and versions 2.6.0+ do not support swagger2. Seems like a conflict in Jackson versions but not quite sure what might be going wrong here. Any help would be useful? Using jackson-databind version 2.10.2 and jackson-datatype version 2.7.2.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java (my-execution) on project schema-service-core: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'pageableOpenAPIConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/SpringDocConfiguration$SpringDocPageableConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pageableOpenAPIConverter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapperProvider' defined in class path resource [org/springdoc/core/SpringDocConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springdoc.core.providers.ObjectMapperProvider]: Factory method 'objectMapperProvider' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MINIMIZE_QUOTES
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: MINIMIZE_QUOTES
at io.swagger.v3.core.util.ObjectMapperFactory.createYaml (ObjectMapperFactory.java:82)
at io.swagger.v3.core.util.ObjectMapperFactory.createYaml (ObjectMapperFactory.java:90)
at io.swagger.v3.core.util.Yaml.mapper (Yaml.java:12)
at org.springdoc.core.providers.ObjectMapperProvider.<init> (ObjectMapperProvider.java:71)
at org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration.objectMapperProvider (SpringDocConfiguration.java:610)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate (SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate (ConstructorResolver.java:653)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:638)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate (DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument (ConstructorResolver.java:887)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray (ConstructorResolver.java:791)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (ConstructorResolver.java:541)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean (AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0 (AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean (AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization (AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh (AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh (ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh (SpringApplication.java:745)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext (SpringApplication.java:420)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:307)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1317)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run (SpringApplication.java:1306)
at com.inmobi.dx.client.codegen.SwaggerSpecGen.runner (SwaggerSpecGen.java:75)
at com.inmobi.dx.client.codegen.SwaggerSpecGen.main (SwaggerSpecGen.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue using all jackson modules of version 2.12.2

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue too and fixed it by updating jackson-dataformat to the latest version from mvnrepository.

Comment: Yeah, got it resolved by using all jackson module of version 2.12.2. Thanks though.